# How to automatically update Kivy label created inside Python using Kivy properties

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to implement the following:

Create a Kivy label inside python using `add_widget()` function. However, I want to benefit from the fact that the label is automatically updated when the text variable has changed (in my case `self.gui_data.number`). I know that I could achieve this when adding the label inside the .kv file, however this is not possible in my case since I need to build up parts of the GUI in run time.

Below you see code for a minimal example. There is a button `add label` which adds the label and the goal is that if one presses the `decrement` button, the label changes. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
  
import parameters


from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher

  
class PongBall(Widget):
    gui_data = parameters.Data()
  
    def add_label(self):
        self.gui_data.number = self.gui_data.number + '5'
        label = Label(text=str(self.gui_data.number))
        self.ids.board.add_widget(label)
  
    def decrement(self):
        self.gui_data.number = self.gui_data.number + '6'
  
    def reset_parameters(self):
        self.gui_data.reset()

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongBall()
        return game
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

parameters.py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
  
  
class Data(EventDispatcher):
    number = StringProperty("0")
     
    def reset(self):
        self.number = "0"
```

pong.kv

```
<PongBall>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: board
     
        Button:
            text: "Add label"
            on_press: root.add_label()
     
        Button:
            text: "Decrement"
            on_press: root.decrement()
     
        Button:
            text: "Reset parameters"
            on_press: root.reset_parameters()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want, you need a `Property` that you can bind to. In the modified version of your code below, I have added a `number` `Property` to the `PongBall` class.

```
class PongBall(Widget):
    gui_data = Data()
    number = StringProperty(gui_data.number)   # Property for binding

    def add_label(self):
        self.gui_data.number = self.gui_data.number + '5'
        label = Label(text=str(self.gui_data.number))

        # bind to the number Property
        self.bind(number=partial(self.number_changed, label))
        
        self.ids.board.add_widget(label)

    def number_changed(self, label, pongball, number):
        # change the Label text
        label.text = number

    def decrement(self):
        self.gui_data.number = self.gui_data.number + '6'

    def reset_parameters(self):
```